# Google Sheets Query: How to Convert Month in Number to Month Name in Text

Tags: google-sheets

I have a very large sheet full of data that I am trying to make a dynamic dashboard for. Currently I have a QUERY formula pulling in the needed data from the master sheet.

```
=QUERY('COPY OF MASTER BOOK'!A1:Z,"
SELECT A, B, C, MONTH(C)+1, YEAR(C) ,E, MONTH(E)+1, YEAR(E), I, MONTH(I)+1, YEAR(I), K, N, MONTH(N)+1, YEAR(N), O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y
LABEL MONTH(C)+1'Shop Complete Month', YEAR(C)'Shop Complete Year',MONTH(E)+1'Shipped Month', YEAR(E)'Shipped Year',MONTH(I)+1'Received Month', YEAR(I)'Received Year',MONTH(N)+1'Approved Month', YEAR(N)'Approved Year'")
```

This is pulling in everything that I need. If you see I am putting `MONTH(C)+1` to pull the month out from the date. It returns the month in digit form. I would like it to be in text form so when I make a pivot table it can show the name instead of the number. I will attach some pictures of the data my QUERY formula is pulling in and what my pivot table looks like.

[Output of QUERY formula. A small sample of the output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnlvo.png)

[Pivot table with numbers. Need month names!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaYHL.png)

How can I make the QUERY formula show month names instead of numbers? I've been working on this all day and can't find a solution on any forum online that works for my situation. Other solutions add the month at the beginning of the query formula or add a formula in the cells outside the query. None of those work because I need to insert the name in the column the numbers are in because my QUERY formula is so large.

Comment: while its possible, you may end up with month names to be in alphabetical order if you will use pivot table

Answer (score 2):

Posting this for a clear answer that @MikeSteelson answered above!

I was originally bringing in the date, the month, and year in three separate columns. I did not need to do that as he mentions; I only need to have one column with the date. This allows me to format the data as a Date, which is important for the Pivot Table.

Once I created the Pivot table I set it up like this.

[image: Pivot Table Settings]

Then I right clicked on any cell in the first column, mine was labeled as "Received Date" and selected Create Pivot Group Date and then selected Month. IMPORTANT: In order to have this option show up in Google Sheets the dates must be formatted as a Date! If it is not then this option will not show for you. I then added a new column in the Pivot Table and clicked on any cell in the row for the new column. And selected Create Pivot Group Date and then selected Year.

It looks like this.

[image: Pivot Table Grouped by Month]
[image: Pivot Table Grouped by Month and Year]

This also fixes the problem of having the Pivot Table sort chronologically and not alphabetically. I hope I was able to explain how I fixed this thanks to the help of @MikeSteelson and @player0

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({'COPY OF MASTER BOOK'!A2:B, 
 TEXT('COPY OF MASTER BOOK'!C2:C, {"m/d/yy", "mmmm", "yyyy"}), 
 TEXT('COPY OF MASTER BOOK'!E2:E, {"m/d/yy", "mmmm", "yyyy"}), 
 TEXT('COPY OF MASTER BOOK'!I2:I, {"m/d/yy", "mmmm", "yyyy"}), 'COPY OF MASTER BOOK'!K2:K, 
 TEXT('COPY OF MASTER BOOK'!N2:N, {"m/d/yy", "mmmm", "yyyy"}), 'COPY OF MASTER BOOK'!O2:Y})
```

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({'COPY OF MASTER BOOK'!A:B, 
 TEXT('COPY OF MASTER BOOK'!C:C, {"m/d/yy", "mmm", "yyyy"}), 
 TEXT('COPY OF MASTER BOOK'!E:E, {"m/d/yy", "mmm", "yyyy"}), 
 TEXT('COPY OF MASTER BOOK'!I:I, {"m/d/yy", "mmm", "yyyy"}), 'COPY OF MASTER BOOK'!K:K, 
 TEXT('COPY OF MASTER BOOK'!N:N, {"m/d/yy", "mmm", "yyyy"}), 'COPY OF MASTER BOOK'!O:Y}, 
 "label Col4'Shop Complete Month',
        Col5'Shop Complete Year',
        Col7'Shipped Month',
        Col8'Shipped Year',
        Col10'Received Month',
        Col11'Received Year',
        Col14'Approved Month',
        Col15'Approved Year'"))
```

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT({'COPY OF MASTER BOOK'!A2:B, 
 TEXT('COPY OF MASTER BOOK'!C2:C, {"m/d/yy", "mm mmmm", "yyyy"}), 
 TEXT('COPY OF MASTER BOOK'!E2:E, {"m/d/yy", "mm mmmm", "yyyy"}), 
 TEXT('COPY OF MASTER BOOK'!I2:I, {"m/d/yy", "mm mmmm", "yyyy"}), 'COPY OF MASTER BOOK'!K2:K, 
 TEXT('COPY OF MASTER BOOK'!N2:N, {"m/d/yy", "mm mmmm", "yyyy"}), 'COPY OF MASTER BOOK'!O2:Y}), 
 "12/30/99", )
```

Comment: This worked to change the month numbers to names. It did bring some new problems with it as well. It is bringing in data in empty cells and giving it a date of 12/30/99. December 30, 1899. I think I can just filter this out but that seems like the wrong thing to do.

Comment: Pivot table is also in alphabetical order like you said. I can't find a way to fix that either

Comment: @KinyonGreen answer updated. (if you dont mind the required month format)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to create new columns with month by number/by text and year.

Create your pivot table, then group the dates by year and monthes. That's all you have to do. You will have the right sorting behavior and monthes in text or as you wish by formatting.

Comment: I could not get this to work. If I use a pivot table and use the entire date as the row instead of the month I get every single date inputted and it's not grouped by month. So I've tried grouping them by month but I don't see that as an option inside the pivot table on Google Sheets.

Comment: Can you share an example spreadsheet? I frequently group by year/month without any difficulty.

Comment: In order to group them by month the date has to be formatted as a date! Then just right click and select Create Pivot Group Date, and then select Month. Worked like a charm!

Comment: The reason it wasn't formatted as a date and wasn't working is because I was using the above formula provided by @player0 which brought in the correct data but not the correct format. Even after I brought it in and tried to format it to a date it wouldn't work. I think it's because of the `TEXT()` formula brought the data and format in as plain text.

Comment: If the `shop complete` column is formatted as date, the group in the pivot table will work normally. And this is far simplier.